# Object.keys brings index values of enum

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following enum

```
export enum IAgentTask {
  firstName,
  lastName,
  idNumber,
  srId,
  srCreationDate,
  selected,
  phoneNumber,
  offerId,
  clientId,
  teamName,
  userFirstName,
  userLastName,
  agentName,
  mainreferrerName
  ....
}
```

I need to get only the key (list of all the options as string) but using `Object.keys(IAgentTask)` bring a list with also the number of the property(26) like this:

`['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', 'firstName', 'lastName']`.....why?

also after using the list to compare the properties of another list-
I want to remove the property of `response.tasks` that are not in test
how can I do it dynamically?

example for response.tasks List of :

```
 agentID: 1
    agentName: ""
    bpaOfferId: null
    clientId: 974543
    companyId: null
```

etc.......

if my `test` list is not contains ('agentID') so remove it from response.tasks

```
let test = this.filteredRowsPreference.map(x => x.fieldDbKey);

for (let j = 0; j < response.tasks.length; j++) {
  let f= Object.keys(IAgentTask);
  for (let key in Object.keys(IAgentTask)) {
    if (!test.includes(key)) {
      delete response.tasks[j][key];
    }
  }
}
```

`response.tasks[j][key]` is `undefined` and I don't want to access every property like this: `response.tasks[j].firstName`

Answer (score 0):

Enums in TS can be accessed both by key and value. When you declare an enum and don't assign values to the keys, they automatically follow a numbered sequence.

If all you need is getting the list of items in the enum, a quick hack would be filtering out things that don't parse to numbers so you omit the implicit values of the enum:

```js
Object.keys(IAgentTask).filter((key) => Number.isNaN(parseInt(key, 10)))
```

Comment: it works! thanks. do you know about the scond part of the question?

Comment: also I want the string not the index` for (let key in Object.keys(IAgentTask).filter((key) => Number.isNaN(parseInt(key, 10)))                  )` key brings the index()

Comment: it does not bring the index. I have tested it, check this in TS playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=87&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgggc1AFwCoEMDOBrKBvAWACgpSoAzASwCdNkA5dCYAGmLKgBssGnX2ylACb1IAI2DU2JMpmowh0jnIDC1YOmSUA9iAAim-jNKZgnYAGNkwRQNIAHABa7goiBKl2o28uUkKlMgtOShQAr2smRmZA0jBTagAxGjpoow54yQAZHjTY73tkAGZ89CQQXhivCHRKEHU-anVqNIF2AF9idgtdTG1zADpObQQACgB5MQArS2QB7GAAT0xR+HK0LGwASgGqTmtqUdGFxa2oAF4APig3DwHKTEZ6Uft0WmAYCuOlligARgADFtgVsgA

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to address this is to use [`string enums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), i.e.

```
export enum IStringAgentTask {
    firstName = 'firstName',
    lastName = 'lastName',
    idNumber = 'idNumber',
    srId = 'srId',
    srCreationDate = 'srCreationDate',
    selected = 'selected',
    phoneNumber = 'phoneNumber',
    offerId = 'offerId',
    clientId = 'clientId',
    teamName = 'teamName',
    userFirstName = 'userFirstName',
    userLastName = 'userLastName',
    agentName = 'agentName',
    mainreferrerName = 'mainreferrerName',
}
```

`Object.keys()` will then yield the following:

```
console.log(Object.keys(IStringAgentTask))
// ["firstName", "lastName", "idNumber", "srId", "srCreationDate", "selected", "phoneNumber", "offerId", "clientId", "teamName", "userFirstName", "userLastName", "agentName", "mainreferrerName"]
```

---

However if you need to use the basic enum (i.e. you prefer/benefit from the numeric value of the enum), you can count on the fact that the array that is produced is twice the length of the number of enum values you have listed, as it contains all of the values (numbers) listed sequentially followed by all of the keys (the enum properties). You can therefore just discard the first half of the array and be left with the same array as in the previous example:

```
export enum IAgentTask {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    idNumber,
    srId,
    srCreationDate,
    selected,
    phoneNumber,
    offerId,
    clientId,
    teamName,
    userFirstName,
    userLastName,
    agentName,
    mainreferrerName,
}

function getEnumValues(): string[] {
    const originalEnumValues: (string | number)[] = Object.keys(IAgentTask);
    const halfOriginalEnumValuesLength = originalEnumValues.length / 2
    return originalEnumValues.splice(halfOriginalEnumValuesLength, halfOriginalEnumValuesLength) as string[]
}

console.log(getEnumValues());
// ["firstName", "lastName", "idNumber", "srId", "srCreationDate", "selected", "phoneNumber", "offerId", "clientId", "teamName", "userFirstName", "userLastName", "agentName", "mainreferrerName"]
```

---

The second part of your question (I believe) asks for an array of objects to have all keys on each object deleted if the key does not exist in the enum list. This could be achieved as follows:

```
const tasks: Record<string, any>[] = [
  {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    keyThatIsNotInTheEnum: '',
  },
  {
    agentName: '',
    agentId: 1
  }
]

function removeNonEnumKeys(tasks: Record<string, any>[]): Record<string, any>[] {
    const enumValues: string[] = Object.keys(IStringAgentTask);
    const tasksToSanitise: Record<string, any>[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tasks)); // duplicate array to prevent mutating the original

    tasksToSanitise
        .forEach(
            task => {
                Object.keys(task)
                    .forEach(key => {
                        if(!enumValues.includes(key)) { delete task[key]; }
                    });
            }
        );

    return tasksToSanitise;
}

console.log(tasks, removeNonEnumKeys(tasks));
// [{ "firstName": "", "lastName": "" }, { "agentName": "" }]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgygFwE4EsQHMCC7QICoCGAzgNZQDeAUAJABmKSRCAcgRMFALxQDk9jLNsB4AaGgBtig9l16SmrdqJooAJs0gAjYElk81GiNqTLqRJDFV7zl0+YDCSYAQQoA9iAAiLjtx4OnF3cvHztgcWAAYwRgKz8icKiY1VMABwALD2BDYz0MrJydUzdaWh1LPRKyixSxakjxFFwKvwamkARbOpi2RV9eHog+0zAEpAAxBgUhPVGdSYFhurmkABkpPtmx9emlOoIcDs2-A9wlmggCNCdqpyRj3kvr4Fudc4BfSkpIjyI3CIAdOI3OgABQAAyYqAwUFAkCgJGAAE8iAAuKAAEnIAHlNAArJIAxEo0HwZBoLCHfDEEgASne4NpXzh0Bg2FwhFIFBo-F2wDq8mk-JU6i0OjqNlUEqQjmcrg83hiEsS0VidXyIGyYqQdSq5SlNDazQN1EGfWWYwWfItOh2Qv2VPNFyuIBuOjuTs+lFoYBA0WCUBwCAAouAIAA1AjiMDAIig2noqEUgDaAF1uVBM1AfiAmFA3Kh0Ggo6HIJHo7H0aCkzCAD5QMPGWlp2S4gnRInIuNsqmcukAbkoWezvwQUHSUdo2MLxfEpYjUZjRFWoHQCHSsgLKCLIBLYfLS6Bq-XUAA9FAAExDrNOBBgJAgfMz3dz-eL2MAoipRqRYCgifiFOz57mW77Lse6QiOOk7Ttus7zgesYrhg660lAxBQDW6BppQXo5n8gLAmC4KaMQKCRLCYYIl26JYkGCFgfGDJMl8+FjggNJolAABKUQFqoAA8WFQQQIBIgAfC23DJteVDDryQrojwyjDoKfRKSpWbEngE6dEQzBuJ0IA6cA84aWImbvBZGZZqcRxCOZ16ZnZnSqOiACM16fKmXw+n68qPk4EBuAAbtkHjzgA0l2oIcaQXG8T8SCCcJ6FiZJqYJjxfHJUJ5IYCJ6UtlQ9SjpRoEVlxWFSVAbaEsS3aINClIcjStKDqVubsZxeBuHAokoK4CTool-F5c1hUSTVABScDYswAKpAQjB-rN82fvlRa0EisWcbS7VnueqhgN+5E+OhSBIAQSJQAgbhQKkThhR0UAQGAHGuDC64cFuO5Rl8po9X1A1DcANDUACtAFsGBCROkoLg4DXKcOJ3LUOj1B1R2DW7aQTIY+jkPQ7D8OIxjxJcKjJUE+jKC0KCACELKIUQAJoA0YCqLGoLEvtaM0+jXMRDEt00smxKph1AufNLZPUO1iMy-Lg40Le96PnFJBEL1-UgINKAJIOeG-P8wBAiCuNa1BQWheFIBRTFmtEPt-ZAA)

Comment: but `(let key in Object.keys(IAgentTask))` key is index(0,1,2 etc) and not the string why?

Comment: `(let key of Object.keys(IStringAgentTask))` will give you the string keys without the numbers. 
`(let key of Object.keys(IAgentTask))` will list the numeric values first, and then the string keys. Use `of` instead of `in` if you want the actual values of an array, `in` returns the index

Comment: you are right. can you help me also with the second part of the question? how can I delete from a list the property that answer my condition? `response.tasks[j][key]` delete the value not the property itself. thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example of `response.tasks` in your question? I can then get a better understanding of what you need to delete/filter

Comment: I added an example. please see if you can help me..Thank you!

Comment: thank you so much! last issue - task is not cost, I am getting it from response of api, it list of class type